# Define the variable to drop among ID duplicates in data.table

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I have the following dataset

```
DT <- data.table(
      id = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7),
      date  = c("2013-11-22","2017-01-24","2020-02-10","2011-01-03"
               ,"2011-01-03","2012-04-03","2010-09-03","2010-09-03"
               ,"2010-05-03"),                         
      status = c("Never","Current","Former",NA,"Former"
                , NA,"Never","Former","Current")
     )
```

I want to create a unique `id` and remove the duplicates.

- The `id` row that should be kept depends on the `status`.
- If staus has `NA` and a non`NA`, I want to keep the non`NA` observation.
- If status has `Former` and `Never`, I want to keep `Former` observation.

Sample output below:

```
    id  date      status 
1:  1 2013-11-22   Never 
2:  2 2017-01-24 Current 
3:  3 2020-02-10  Former 
4:  4 2011-01-03  Former 
5:  5 2012-04-03    <NA> 
6:  6 2010-09-03  Former 
7:  7 2010-05-03 Current
```

The original dataset has more rows and columns and a `data.table` function would be time efficient. Also some `id` occur more than one time. I tried it before to keep the `id` with the latest date. But than, I have too many 'NA' that had another status entry for an earlier date.

How can I define for identical `id` which `status` should be kept?

Comment: Please include your expected output for the sample data you give. I'm unclear about the statement "*The id row that should be kept depends on the status. If it is NA and a nonNA status,*". If *what* is `NA` and a non-`NA` status?

Comment: The output should be the following   `id       date  status
1:  1 2013-11-22   Never
2:  2 2017-01-24 Current
3:  3 2020-02-10  Former
4:  4 2011-01-03  Former
5:  5 2012-04-03    <NA>
6:  6 2010-09-03  Former
7:  7 2010-05-03 Current`

Comment: Please edit the post to show that information.

Answer (score 3):

We could create a `factor` with `status` specifying the `levels`, use that to `order` along with 'id' and get the `unique` by 'id'

```
library(data.table)
unique(DT[order(id, ordered(status, c("Former", "Current", "Never")))], by = 'id')
```